# Identity for multi-tenant app allowing duplicatie email or username

Tags: asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant web/mobile application that uses `Asp.Net Identity` for its membership/authentication. Users can use the app via an android app or directly via the web interface. They must register to use the application.

The problem is a user with a single email/username/phone number can not register in more than one tenant simultaneously. For example imagine a tenant is dedicated to an accounting and another is dedicated to messaging. A user wants to register in both of them with one unique email/username/phone. But `Identity` does not allow duplicate email/username/phone naturally.

I have introduced an `AppId` in the `IdentityUser` entity. So it is obvious that what user belongs to what application. A workaround is to use `AppId`. For example attaching `AppId` in front of `username` to make it unique.

Is there any good design for this scenario?

Comment: I think rather than adding multiple accounts, have only a single account and add claims to what tenant they have access to.

Comment: @trailmax That's a good point but the client wants to have option that no one knows these apps are hosted with same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement your own validation rules for user accounts, you will have to implement your own `IIdentityValidator<TUser>`. Probably the easiest way would be to inherit from framework's `UserValidator<TUser>` class ([see source here](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs)) and override relevant parts of the class. This is useful if you would like to add username/email uniqueness within your tenants, but allow for same emails to be used across different tenants.

And once you have your implementation, you plug it into `UserManager.UserValidator` that takes an instance of `IIdentityValidator<TUser>`